# What diferrent with get()->count() and count()

Tags: php, laravel

have deployed my laravel apps in VPS
have confused with this result query ORM

```
Company::where('active', 'Yes')->count()

it result 0
```

when i try change my ORM

```
Company::where("active", "Yes")->get()->count();`

it result 8
```

but when my apps in localhost

```
Company::where('active', 'Yes')->count()

it result 8
```

Comment: So when you execute your two examples on your remote machine you get different results and when you execute them locally you get the same result?

Comment: yes sir, but it resolved, because i forget to flush my model cache

Comment: Great! Let me just add that your second example is probably very inefficient. I don't know about your caching, but the worst case is that `->get()` will first fetch a collection of all rows from the database and `->count()` will then count them locally. If you use `->count()` directly, your database application will count the rows for you and just return the number.

Comment: aha i get it, thank you sir @TheBlackIPs

Answer (score 0):

it resolved 
because i forget to flush my model cache

thanks everyone